# Why can't users access my website via the root link?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have an asp.net MVC website (4.5.1) that uses Windows Authentication. I am allowing access for users of a certain AD security group. That AD Sec group also has read access on my SQL DB. My issue is that when users in that group try to access the root url of my site, they get a 401 Access Denied error. However, when they access the pages directly (the same page that the root page loads), they can access them, no problem.

website.com/orgbrowser -> 401 error

website.com/orgbrowser/home -> no error

website.com/orgbrowser/home/search -> no error

My routeconfig loads /home/search as default. The error doesn't occur for my admin user, and I am correctly shown /home/search when I go to website.com/orgbrowser.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Search", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

My security set-up in web.config:

```
<system.web>
  <compilation targetFramework="4.5.1" />
  <customErrors mode="Off" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
  <authentication mode="Windows" />
  <authorization>
    <allow roles="ADSec Group Name"/>
    <deny users="*" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Am I doing something wrong in my route config (or anywhere else in my asp.net code), or is this perhaps an issue with IIS or SQL security settings?

EDIT: I've given the AD security group read permissions on the folder on my server that contains the webpage. Now it works. Should I have to explicitly have to give users those permissions? Shouldn't I just have to add the App Pool user, and the web-app takes care of permissions?

Comment: There must be something else here. Do you have a `default.aspx` or `index.aspx` file in the root perhaps?

Comment: No, none of those files

Comment: It seems "Home" is your controller but what is orgbrowser ?

Comment: It's the virtual directory the app is running under. It is the root of my application

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to explicitly give the AD security group read permissions on the folder of my webpage on the Windows server. I'm not really happy with this, as I believe this should be solved by giving the app pool user those permissions, but that did not work, nor did anything involving giving IUSRs permissions.